# How to compile PHP5 into Apache 2 statically?

Tags: apache2

Is it possible to compile php5 (or really any php version) into the apache2 binary?

I'm not looking to install & load php as a shared module. What I'm trying to find out is whether or not it's even possible to compile php5 into apache2 statically.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Rwe

Answer (score 1):

I bet you were looking for a way to improve performance.

The answer is, no, you can't in Apache2.

Answer (score -1):

yeah its not a problem, first ./configure and build php using:

```
--with-apache=../path/to/apache-2
```

then ./configure apache with:

```
--activate-module=src/modules/php5/libmodphp5.a \
```

From http://php.net/manual/en/configure.about.php:

```
--with-apache[=DIR]

Build a static Apache module. DIR is the top-level Apache build
directory, defaults to /usr/local/apache.
```

Comment: Your method applies only to Apache 1 but not to Apache 2. Under Apache 2, there is no subdirectory src/modules.

Rwe